# Can i save result of a sql query in a property directly in ant

Tags: sql, ant

I want to save the sql query result into a property in ant. I know i can do it through  a file. But can i assign it to a property by directly declaring a  property.

eg: `select count(colname) from tablename`.

So i want to assign count value to a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't do this using the standard ant sql task.

Use a [groovy script](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task) to set the property as follows:

```
<target name="query">
    <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="build.path"/>

    <groovy>
    import groovy.sql.Sql

    def sql = Sql.newInstance(properties."db.url", properties."db.user", properties."db.pass", properties."db.driver")
    def row = sql.firstRow("SELECT count(*) from example1")

    properties."row.count" = row[0]
    </groovy>
</target>

<target name="result" depends="query">
    <echo message="Row count: ${row.count}"/>
</target>
```