# How to store SQL select query data as name value pair through ant

Tags: sql, ant

I am using ant script for selecting data from dbms.

```
<target name="change">
    <echo message="${DatabaseUrl}"/>
    <sql>  
        select query
    </sql>
    <loadfile srcfile="temp.properties" property="result"/>
    <echo message="${result}"/>
</target>
```

The output of this is like as

```
 ServerName,HostName,Location
 Win@k8,DS,India
 Linux,DS1,India
```

I want that output to be like

```
 ServerName=Win@k8
 HostName=DS
 Location=India
```

etc....

So that I can store the value in variable for further processing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can i save result of a sql query in a property directly in ant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800812/can-i-save-result-of-a-sql-query-in-a-property-directly-in-ant)

Comment: yes u can like in sql task there are few more attributes like  print="true" and output="temp.properties". By using them u can get the result.There are few more options like expandProperties="true"  showtrailers="false" rowcountproperty="yes". U can also use them based upon requirement.